# Как вывести файл в браузер PHP без загрузки?

Tags: php

Как выдать файл в браузер через PHP, без скачивания?
Я использовал вот такое

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='" . basename($filename) . "'");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($local_filename));
header('Content-type: '.$mimeType.';');
readfile($local_filename);
```

Но файл сразу скачивается... 
Мне надо чтоб по ссылке он выдавался, чтоб я эту ссылку мог использовать в плеере

Comment: попробуйте убрать строчку с `Content-Disposition: attachment...` – это заставляет браузер сохранять файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ свой вы уже практически привели: файл выдаётся при помощи PHP.

Что с этим будет делать браузер -- зависит от mime type 
Например, если  Content-type: text/plain - то браузер попытается просто отобразить содержимое. При значении Content-type: application/octet-stream (это все бинарные файлы и файлы, mime тип которых веб-сервер не знает) браузер может предлагать скачать файл (особенно при при установленном Content-Disposition: attachment)

Поэтому формальный ответ - проставьте принудительно text/plain и уберите Content-Disposition: attachment если есть. При этом в окне браузера вы увидите мешанину символов - но сможете из адресной строки скопировать url для вставки в браузер.

Однако, это решение задачи в лоб. Во-первых, вы на экране видите лишний мусор (причём большой, если у вас аудио или видео файл); во-вторых, плейер может перестать работать при неверном типе миме.

Подумайте над тем, чтобы решать не вашу текущую задачу, а просто выводить в браузер список файлов в папке: эту задачу можно решать как при помощи PHP, так и даже вообще обойтись без кода (настройка веб-сервера Apache сводится к одной строке).