# Преобразовать base64 в PDF с помощью CURL

Tags: php, curl, pdf, base64

Есть код CURL, который отправляет данные с формы на сервер post запросом, преобразуя их в json. Ответ приходит в виде base64, в нём находится pdf файл. Подскажите, как мне base64 преобразовать в pdf файл и вывести на экран. Заранее благодарен за ответы!

Код:

```
<?php
$login=$_POST["login"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$fields = array(
    'login' => $login,
    'password' => $password
    
);
$test = json_encode($fields);
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $curl = curl_init(); //инициализация сеанса
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'url_servera'); //урл сайта к которому обращаемся
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //выводим заголовки
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //передача данных методом POST
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //теперь curl вернет нам ответ, а не выведет
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $test); //тут переменные которые будут переданы методом POST
    
    $test = json_encode($fields);
    $res = curl_exec($curl);
    //если ошибка то печатаем номер и сообщение
    if(!$res) {
        $error = curl_error($curl).'('.curl_errno($curl).')';
        echo $error;
        curl_close($curl);
        
        
    }
        
    
}

?>
```

Сейчас ответ выводится на экран:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674532/how-to-display-base64-encoded-pdf)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov там немного другой язык. Возможно автору будет достаточно https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.base64-decode.php и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552158/Как-вывести-файл-в-браузер-php-без-загрузки